# Listen firestore by where condition from reference type

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning flutter and also new with firestore too, try implement and got this situation.

I have the `Account` document with document ID is a generator like `KCeEhT9NwFURl0xirRrU` and the `Book` document with have to reference with `Account`, now I want to create a listen for any change of `Book` with a specifical account by email, I try but don't work.

```
var accountRef = firestore.collection('Account')
  .where("email", isEqualTo: email)
  .reference()
  .document();
firestore.collection('Book')
  .where('assigner', isEqualTo: accountRef)
  .where('status', isGreaterThan: 0)
  .snapshots()
  .listen((query) async {
    List<Book> books = <Book>[];
    for (var documentChange in query.documentChanges) {
      var book = await Book.fromMap(documentChange.document.data);
      books.add(book);
    }
    print(books);
  }
);
```

If I use this it work, but I don't remember document ID

```
var accountRef = firestore.collection('Account').document('KCeEhT9NwFURl0xirRrU');
```

I just want to filter by email, any help, thank.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  where("email", "==", email)
```

Comment: Thanks, but in Dart not use this syntax.